# Managing Thousands of Test scripts using TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests, testng

Suppose if there are are 2000+ test scripts written using Java+selenium+TestNG with ExtentReports .
What is the best way to handle the below problems :

1. How can on easily mark scripts (which scripts to run and stop) without going through a huge testng.xml ?
2. Documentation of each script.
3. Managing multiple test suites with multiple sub modules each containing scripts .And finally visualizing all the reports suite/module/script wise in report

Ideally I like the UI of Robot RIDE and the ease and flexibility of managing test scripts .But looking for a non Robot solution .

Answer (score 0):

For point 1: please group your test scripts and from xml select the specific group to run, so that testscripts in that group alone can be executed.Other testscripts will  not be executed.

@Test (groups = { "smoketest", "Endtoendflow" })

Include below tags in xml under test.

```
        <groups>    
            <run>   
                 <include name="smoketest" />   
            </run>  
        </groups>
```